# User deleting content of most of their questions

Tags: discussion, support, questions

I have spotted a user who seems to be systematically removing the content of their previous questions, not deleting them. The questions have answers and usually one has been accepted. however the threads now make no sense and I presume it wouldn't help the searchability.

what should be done? What is the SO etiquette?

1. report the user
2. roll-back the questions
3. flag the questions
4. do nothing
5. other

Comment: I saw your flag, so I rolled back the deletions and warned the user. Thanks for your help!

Comment: WOW! 91 answers in 14 days? You should get some sleep :)

Comment: @HuBeZa that's only 6.5 per day how's one supposed to catch up if they sleep ;)

Comment: Thanks for being an awesome user! :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Good catch, and definitely reporting-worthy!

Make a moderator aware of the situation by flagging one of the user's questions, and explaining what he's doing. A moderator will roll back the changes.

Comment: Anyone with 2K+ rep can do it, but only moderator can also Lock the question preventing the OP to remove the contents again. :-)

Comment: OK have done.. thanks for quick answer! @ShadowWizard, less than 2k would rule me out anyway ;)

Answer (score 20):

Note that there are actually hard, system enforced limits on how many old posts a user can modify per day *specifically* to prevent this kind of [ragequit](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/rage-quit) "I'm taking my ball and going home" behavior.

[image: Mr. Rage Quit]

So I'd be curious to see where you are seeing this, because it's not really possible to do any more without incredible patience.

Comment: Really? People get so annoyed of SO that they using [scorched earth tactics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scorched_earth)? I guessed it is an account that have been hacked by a bored teenager.

Comment: Screw you guys, I'm going home. And I'm taking the basketball field my parents paid for with me. Piece by piece.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood, could have been "rage quit" at least that's the only reason I could think of, the content removed wasn't earth shattering & user history shows no reason why this should be the case; except they haven't logged on in over a month. it was not mega major (6 posts out of 7 or 8) - maybe why system didn't pick it up? I only found it because I genuinely saw a question/answer that interested me pop to the top of my list which of course turned out to be old, just edited - I don't like to 'out' in public (old school ;)) so I'll just go get some sleep now.. it's never 91 is it.. eeek!!

Comment: @Pekka's trolling account  oh no you don't! I paid for it too by providing a child to play on it.. scoot will you!

Comment: @Jeff off topic. Didn't you suggest a "too easy, look it up in the manual" close reason recently? I can't find it, no matter how hard I search. Can you point me to the right link? Or was it a dream?

Comment: Ah, @mootinator [found it](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/590980#590980). Is there any news on that? Will it be discussed on Meta at some point?