# What's the official position about the multiple deletion of own posts?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools, deleted-answers, moderators

This question is quite related to this one: [How to best handle the "Possible vandalism of own posts" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94421/how-to-best-handle-the-possible-vandalism-of-own-posts-flag), but I would not like to narrow it to the case discussed in that question. More importantly, this question is about what should we, mere non-diamond mortals, do about the automatic *possible vandalism* flag.

When is it OK to delete several posts and when it is not fine? Will ♦ moderators undelete the posts if they're good? How good have them to be so it's worth undeleting them? What would that assessment be based on (votes, subjective evaluation of the answer's quality, etc.)?

**In short, I'm trying to understand when should we flag those actions and when should we just ignore them (or, perhaps, marking them as an invalid flag).**

Comment: Related: [Does systematic self-deleting need to be prevented?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74466)

Comment: All the "possible vandalism" warnings I've seen so far was users deleting their 0-voted answers - presumably in an effort to improve their statistics. While it's debatable whether it's the right thing to give in voting behaviour like that, I think it's legitimate enough. Maybe that specific scenario should be excluded from the warning

Comment: Related: [Slight modification to the “suspected vandalism” algorithm](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82884/60761)

Comment: I found posting less answers to be a good workaround for these restrictions.  Vote to close instead of posting a speculative answer.

Comment: @Pekka thanks for that link. Clearly related to this one. With regard to your other comment, I think that's exactly the debate that should take place now, so we can set up some guideline on how to proceed. If not, it is too subjective

Comment: @Henk that would then assume that nothing should be done in those cases. While I do not really disagree with that, as I said above, I'd like to see some guideline based on the community consensus.

Comment: @alea - doesn't sound like you read Henk's link.

Comment: @Hans my response to Henk demonstrates I did. I believe you're talking about my response to you. I remove that comment because clearly I did not understand your comment, and I admit it was quite off topic with the question.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216846/162102

Answer (score 6):

I don't mind it when

- cleaning up *redundant* answers on questions that have multiple alternate good answers
- cleaning up old, "less awesome" answers that are no longer reflective of the user's current skill level

I *do* mind it, however, when

- arbitrarily removing great and useful answers from questions
- mindlessly deleting your content in [a "ragequit" fashion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85786/user-deleting-content-of-most-of-their-questions/85792#85792)
- removing great answers just because they don't have any upvotes

So, which case is it?

Comment: This makes sense. It starts delineating the guideline I was talking about. The flags I've seen until now are clearly the first two cases, but I do not want to limit this question to one flag in particular. It's still unclear to me though the definition of "less awesome" and "great". Does "correct" count at all?