# Self-deleting answers

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, faq-update-request

I know that users are discouraged from deleting their own answers, especially if they are highly upvoted and contribute to the overall answer of the solution. I can't find anywhere where these guidelines come in to play, except a person can't delete their answer if it is accepted. Are there any official guidelines relating to deleting one's own answer?

FYI, the moderator template for this ban is:

> I'm writing in reference to your Space Exploration Stack Exchange
>   account:
>
> You have recently removed or defaced a lot of content from your posts.
>   Please note that once you post a question or answer to this site,
>   those posts become part of the collective efforts of others who have
>   also contributed to that content. Posts that are potentially useful to
>   others should not be removed except under extraordinary circumstances.
>   Even if the post is no longer useful to the original author, that
>   information is still beneficial to others who may run into similar
>   problems in the future - this is the underlying philosophy of Stack
>   Exchange.
>
> Extensive deletions take a lot of effort to repair. I have placed your
>   account on hold while I reach out to you to avoid any further
>   misunderstandings. Once this matter has been resolved, your reputation
>   score will be restored and your account will resume as normal.
>
> Please respond to this message. I sincerely hope this is just a
>   misunderstanding, but if you feel you have an exceptional reason to
>   remove this content then let me know. If you'd prefer, you can contact
>   Stack Exchange directly through the 'contact us' link at the bottom of
>   the site.

Comment: If you do it too many times with positive or zero score answers you'll get a suspension for vandalism. Speaking from experience.

Comment: Right. This came up because I'm a moderator and I executed such a policy. The user asked me where that was in the FAQ, and I can't point anything to them.

Comment: I don't think I can access the messages from the mods so I can't check if a link was cited. Mod JohnB on GDSE knows something about if you'd like to ping him in the GD chatroom.

Comment: related: [Why was BalusC temporarily suspended from SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288242/839601)

Comment: Duplicate? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/216846/162102  I would say yes except that I can't tell if you're asking about deleting *occasional* answers, like the other question, or *many* of them, like the mod message.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: The other question answers this one quite well. If one day you try to clean your posts, and delete let's say 7 of them because another answer has been accepted and yours is not so good after all, then you are put on hold. I find the associated message too much aggressive, it suspects you are guilty until you prove you are not. It should be done differently, asking only about reasons, without an implicit threat, or better: replace the "Delete" button by "Request Deletion Review", which would request an agreement from 4 or 5 other users.

Comment: @MonicaCellio: That question does have an answer, although I believe I would like to see this explained clearer in the FAQ somehow. I know it's in the legalese section, but it'd be nice to have something in English too.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it does say when you should remove your own answer in the [Help Center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers):

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed. This includes answers that are:

> - commentary on the question or other answers

- asking another, different question
- “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
- exact duplicates of other answers
- barely more than a link to an external site
- not even a partial answer to the actual question

> ...
> Answers can be deleted at any time by their authors, unless the answer has been accepted by the question asker.

And as a [legal](https://stackexchange.com/legal) document:

> You agree that all Subscriber Content that You contribute to the Network is perpetually and irrevocably licensed to Stack Exchange under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license. **You grant Stack Exchange the perpetual and irrevocable right and license to use, copy, cache, publish, display, distribute, modify, create derivative works and store such Subscriber Content and to allow others to do so in any medium now known or hereinafter developed (“Content License”) in order to provide the Services, even if such Subscriber Content has been contributed and subsequently removed by You. ***

In both cases, the user will remove his/her own answer if the answer seems to be salvageable and no longer able to help the community effectively. Answers can also be removed by the author if he or she assumes that the answer is no revleance or will be heavily criticized. If the user removes too many answers, the user in question might no longer be able to post [answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/answer-bans):

> These filters help keep the quality of our sites high. The exact formula for the bans is not disclosed, but users are only banned if they have a significant number of heavily down-voted, zero-voted, or deleted posts.

Seemingly, there is no official guideline about self-deletion of a user's answer. The quotes above are related but not about extensive self-deletion of answers policies other than an answer ban.

Comment: None of the things that you've quoted have stated that deleting good content is vandalism or inappropriate.  Your first quote is simply stating when mods/users may delete your content, not when you can/can't delete your own content, the second point is merely stating that SE can use the content that you post whether you want them to or not, which doesn't mean deleting good content is vandalism, and the last point says you may be banned from posting if you post a lot of low quality content, which is also unrelated to being banned for vandalizing (through deletion) good content.

Comment: @Servy, agreed. I edited my post to match what you said.

Comment: So why are you posting a whole bunch of content only to follow it up with, "oh yeah, all of that stuff that I just said, it's all irrelevant".  Why make the reader waste several minutes of their life reading something that you're only going to tell them doesn't matter.

Comment: Because they are ***related*** to the issue at hand.

Comment: Quite distantly, and not in any way relevant to actually getting an answer.  I mean, if you allow any number layers of indirection *everything* is related to *everything* in *some* way.  At the end of the day if you're trying to explain to someone why vandalizing their own good content is wrong, there's just no reason to be explaining to them why bad things will happen if they post lots of bad content.  It's just not relevant to the issue at hand of deleting good content.

Comment: Those two statements are confusing and do not provide meaningful rules for the user: 1. "*Answers can be deleted at any time by their authors, unless the answer has been accepted by the question asker*", and 2. "*If the user removes too many answers, the user in question might no longer be able to post answers*". What is "*too many*"? Especially if the criteria do not take into account the quality of what is removed.